# Replace x-ticks with evenly spaced timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to insert `timestamps` on the `x-axis` for a `scatter plot` instead of `total seconds`. Below is what I have tried thus far but I'm getting an `error` with this line;

```
loc, labels = ax.set_xticks(x)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = ({
    'A' : ['08:00:00','08:10:00','08:12:00','08:26:00','08:29:00','08:31:00','10:10:00','10:25:00','10:29:00','10:31:00'],
    'B' : ['1','1','1','2','2','2','7','7','7','7'],     
    'C' : ['X','Y','Z','X','Y','Z','A','X','Y','Z'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

x = df['A']
y = df['B']

x_numbers = (pd.to_timedelta(df['A']).dt.total_seconds())

ax.scatter(x_numbers, y)
loc, labels = ax.set_xticks(x)
newlabels = [str(pd.Timedelta(str(i)+ ' seconds')).split()[2] for i in loc]
ax.set_xticks(loc, newlabels)
```

**Note**
I need to use `ax` instead of `plt` as this plot is called as a `subplot`. If I use plot, the `axis` will be assigned to the last `subplot` instead of the designated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use datetimes directly without messing with the ticklabels. Using a `matplotlib.dates.MinuteLocator` in addition can give you nice positions of the ticks.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

d = ({
    'A' : ['08:00:00','08:10:00','08:12:00','08:26:00','08:29:00','08:31:00',
           '10:10:00','10:25:00','10:29:00','10:31:00'],
    'B' : ['1','1','1','2','2','2','7','7','7','7'],     
    'C' : ['X','Y','Z','X','Y','Z','A','X','Y','Z'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(df["A"].values, df["B"].values)
ax.set_xlim(df["A"].min(), df["A"].max())

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator((0,30)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M"))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, this is great. What if the timestamps go over 24Hr though?

Comment: Then they need to carry a date with them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:
Edit: Changes made to make sure axis and subplot is used

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = ({
'A' : ['08:00:00','08:10:00','08:12:00','08:26:00','08:29:00','08:31:00','10:10:00','10:25:00','10:29:00','10:31:00'],
'B' : ['1','1','1','2','2','2','7','7','7','7'],     
'C' : ['X','Y','Z','X','Y','Z','A','X','Y','Z'],
})

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

x = df['A']
y = df['B']

x_numbers = (pd.to_timedelta(df['A']).dt.total_seconds())


ax.scatter(x_numbers, y)
plt.sca(ax) # gets handle on the current axis
loc, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.xticks(loc, [str(a) for a in x])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a guess, but if you want to replace the x-axis labels give this a try.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = ({
    'A' : ['08:00:00','08:10:00','08:12:00','08:26:00','08:29:00','08:31:00','10:10:00','10:25:00','10:29:00','10:31:00'],
    'B' : ['1','1','1','2','2','2','7','7','7','7'],     
    'C' : ['X','Y','Z','X','Y','Z','A','X','Y','Z'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
x = df['A']
y = df['B']
x_numbers = (pd.to_timedelta(df['A']).dt.total_seconds())

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
ax.scatter(x_numbers, y)

xLabel = [str(int(num)) + ' seconds' for num in x_numbers]
ax.set_xticklabels(xLabel)

plt.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```